# Delphi 2010 compiled application has wrong styling and renders solid labels

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm a high school student forced to code in Delphi 2010. I recently deleted `.res` and `.identcache` files and now the application does not render correctly

[image: see here]

[image: and here]

Please advise. I'm running the latest Windows 10, so these XP-like styling issues don't make sense to me

Comment: "forced to code in Delphi 2010" It's not *that* bad, is it?

Comment: Anyhow: Go to the project settings dialog and enable manifest/runtime themes.

Comment: "*I recently deleted `.res` and `.identcache` files*" - why did you delete the `.res` files? Sounds like one of them [contained a Visual Styles manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) for the application.